# pass variables between two controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two controllers: tasks, tasksperson.

I have views/tasks/index.html.erb:

```
<table>
    <% @tasks.group_by(&:name).each do |name, tasks| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= name %></td>
      <td><%= tasks.size %></td>
      <td><%= tasks.select{ |task| task.done != true }.size %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
</table>
```

**I want to create a link in views/tasks/index.html to views/tasksperson/index.html.erb.I want also to send the name into 'index' in Tasksperson_controller.. I tried to do this by getting params[:name] but I think it's wrong**

**maybe, I need to do something like:**

```
<td><%= link_to 'Show Tasks', tasksperson_path(name) %></td>
```

this is my tasksperson_controller:

```
class TaskspersonController < ApplicationController
    def index
       @tasks = Task.where(:name => params[:name]) respond_to do |format|
          format.html # index.html.erb
          format.json { render json: @tasks }
       end
    end
end
```

and views/tasksperson/index.html.erb:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>num of tasks</th>
    <th>num tasks left</th>
    <th>test</th>
  </tr>

  <% @tasks.each do |f| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= f.name %></td>
    <td><%= f.task %></td>
    <td><%= f.done %></td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Comment: can you show us your data models? i.e. does a TaskPerson have many Tasks or does a Task have many TaskPersons, or maybe a Task has and belongs to a TaskPerson (i.e. Tasks can be worked on by multiple People)

Comment: @house9, the 'Tasks' contains all the tasks and taskperson have to caontain all the task of person X, so Task have many taskpersons. I have to define it? how can I define it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `:name` as a parameter to the rule that defines the route to `TaskspersonController#index` in `routes.rb`
so it would be something like this:

`match 'tasksperson/index/:name' => 'tasksperson#index', as: :tasksperson_path`

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment "*...so Task have many taskpersons*" I think you want a data model similar to below

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assigned_tasks
  has_many :people, :through => :assigned_tasks
end

# maybe this is just the User class?
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :assigned_tasks
  has_many :tasks, :through => :assigned_tasks
end

# was TaskPerson
class AssignedTask < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :task
  belongs_to :person
end
```

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association for information about "The has_many :through Association"

```
task = Task.create(:title => "Go up the hill")
jack = Person.find(00000)
jill = Person.find(00000)

task.people << jack
task.people << jill

task.assigned_tasks.each do |join|
  puts join.created_at
  puts join.person.name
  # 0 - jack
  # 1 - jill
end

task.people.each do |person|
  puts person.name
end
```

I am not exactly sure what you are trying to display in your views, it looks like you are grouping by a task name attribute in task/index, is that the Persons name?